# Register Transfer Notation in MIPS assembler

Tags: assembly, mips

What is a correct notation of these two instructions?

```
 lw $t1, array($t2) 
 la $t3, address
```

I think that it would be

```
Reg[t1] := Memory[array + t2]
Reg[t3] := address
```

But I am not sure. Because if lw loads content of memory, then la will load only address, am I right?

```
lw $t1, address # Reg[t1] = Memory[address]
```

Comment: Note that `la` is only a pseudo-instruction, the machine never even sees it directly.  Same for `lw` with a label address, unless that label happens to be in the low 16 bits of address space so the assembler can use a single `lw imm16($zero)` instruction without `lui`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are correct for `lw` but not for `la`.

`la $t3,address` translates to

```
lui $at, 4097 (0x1001 → upper 16 bits of $at).
ori $t3,$at,disp
```

where the immediate (`disp`) is the number of bytes between the first data location (always 0x1001'0000) and the address of the first byte in the string

Comment: so can the la be written is notation similiar to this one I provided?

Comment: in special cases probably. Look here : http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Mips/pseudo.html

Comment: George (and @Mateusz): `lw $reg, address` is also a pseudo-instruction, using `lui` / `lw`.  (Unless you're using MARS or something configured with the data section starting at a low address, so `lw $t1, address` can assemble to `lw $t1, address($zero)`, i.e. the full address fitting in the 16-bit-sign-extended displacement in the I-type `lw` instruction.)  So the question is correct about the *first* `lw`, but the second `lw` is the same as the `la`, whether you consider that right or wrong.  Note that `$at` isn't needed here; you can `lui` / `ori` both into `$t3`